# Using mx components in an "actionscript project" in Flash Builder

Tags: apache-flex, components, builder

In Flash builder, I want to create an "Actionscript Project" that uses the mx datagrid component. Unfortunately the mx/spark components don't seem to be available unless your project is a "flex project". Is there a way around this?  (I really don't like using that mxml mark-up, and just want to write pure code)

thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In ActionScript Build Path, you have to manually add SWC libraries outside Flex library as shown below (add additional libraries as per your requirement):
[image]

Comment: Thanks Rahul, that did it! It seems strange that adobe didn't make it part of the project-creation wizard. Evidently, they think that those who don't use mxml aren't interested in using components.

Comment: @user3508264 Glad that helped you. Can you please accept my answer as main answer upvote it?